# Taxnomy term name not searched in exposed filter in view!

Tags: views

when i searched title that result showing fine but i searched taxonomy term like movies,result not showing even i searched body content result showing fine.
add filter-> Global combined filter and then tick to exposed, and select single filter then operator to be contains and select content:title,content:category, content:body.

[image: imgur.com/bfcnf.png]

[image]